# Intermittent SSL error in iOS for NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, nsurlconnection

I am connecting to a server with a custom SSL which is no longer a valid SSL Certificate. I have updated my info.plist to allow arbitrary and added code to bypass challenge on NSURLConnection delegate.

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
NSLog(@"willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge");
BOOL trusted = NO;
if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
    NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cert" ofType:@"der"];
    NSData *certData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:thePath];
    CFDataRef certDataRef = (__bridge_retained CFDataRef)certData;
    SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, certDataRef);
    SecPolicyRef policyRef = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();
    SecCertificateRef certArray[1] = { cert };
    CFArrayRef certArrayRef = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (void *)certArray, 1, NULL);
    SecTrustRef serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;
    SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(serverTrust, certArrayRef);
    SecTrustResultType trustResult;
    SecTrustEvaluate(serverTrust, &trustResult);
    trusted = (trustResult == kSecTrustResultUnspecified);
    CFRelease(certArrayRef);
    CFRelease(policyRef);
    CFRelease(cert);
    CFRelease(certDataRef);
}
if (trusted) {
    [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
} else {
    [challenge.sender performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
}
```

However, intermittently happening, I am getting the SSL error. It is not calling the delegate `willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge` instead going directly to `didFailWithError` delegate.

`-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is subtly wrong.  The cert is trusted if the result status is either:

- kSecTrustResultUnspecified
- kSecTrustResultProceed

Additionally, for an expired cert, the code above should see a kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure error unless you call:

```
SecTrustSetOptions(serverTrust,kSecTrustOptionAllowExpired);
```

However, allowing expired certificates is strongly discouraged.

Unless by "no longer valid", you mean that it violates the minimum requirements for iOS 9, in which case yes, you'll get exactly the behavior you described when running on iOS 9, if compiled against the iOS 9 SDK.  For more info, do a Google search for App Transport Security.